# Video carousel in SXA Sitecore 10

Tags: sxa

Why datasource in carousel is limited to image, what do we need to do if we have to use list of Videos as datasource in carousel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The data source of the carousel is not limited to an image. The Carousel is a composite component. It is using child grouping data source items and each child item (carousel slide) has its own layout:
[image]

By default, each slide contains an image but you can simply remove it in Experience Editor and add a video there. Which would result in Carousel with videos.